# Git 3 branches merge with every 2 branches having no conflict

Tags: git, merge, branch, git-commit

I am discussing about git merge issues with a colleague of mine. And I come to a question. There are three branches from a same branch: `b1 b2 b3`. The three branches have unique modifications(commits). But everyone of them can be merge into any other one without conflict. Then there mustn't be conflicts when merging these three branches into one, is it correct?

A simple example(b-branch  &  c-commit):

```
b1 : c1->c2->c3->c4  
b2 : c1->c2->c3->c5->c6  
b3 : c1->c2->c3->c5->c7  
b1 can merge into b2 without conflict  
b2 can merge into b3 without conflict  
b3 can merge into b1 without conflict
```

When we merge `b1` and `b2` into `b3`, is it possible that this action will result in a conflict?

In this question, we have a precondition that these 3 branches are created from the same branch, and commits from the parent branch can not be modified(with rebase or other command).

Comment: in your situation, you cannot perform fast-forward merges

Comment: I think your assumption about conflicts is correct: given this scenario, I don't see how you'd get conflicts from any merges.

Comment: OK, I'll correct it. What I mean is that every 2 branches have no conflict.

Comment: @w0lf What if the commit history has been modified?  For example, the b2 becomes :  c1->c3->c5->c6

Comment: I'm not sure what type of history rewrites your precondition is intended to exclude; it's unlikely that matters. But what *does* matter is, what merge strategies are allowed - because conflict definition is strategy-specific. And, are "evil merges" (merges interrupted with `--no-commit` or otherwise `amend`ed) allowed? Note that octopus merges always use a different strategy than the normal default

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger To be simple, firstly we just discuss about simple commits: no modification to history commits, commits from parent branches are unchanged. New commits to different branches are also different(ex. `c6` cannot be --amend by `c4`, they are just irrelevance.)